# Remove #id from the browser url on page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am building a multistep form using VueJS seen here: [staging.evbox.com/quote](http://staging.evbox.com/quote) . I have added a step hash id in the url as the user moves through the steps but I would like to remove the step #id when the user performs a page refresh. I have tried the following but it does not work. Can anyone help?

```
 mounted: function () {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
            history.pushState('', '', window.location.pathname)
        });}
```

Comment: What's the point of having a unique URL per step in the first place if you are going to bounce the user back to the first step if they refresh the page?

Comment: Hmm, good point.

Comment: do you have other `beforeunload` bindings ?

Comment: No, I don't have any other beforeunload bindings.